# Pyspark question making count result into a dataframe

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark function that looks like this. \

```
spark.sql("select count(*) from student_table where student_id is NULL") \
spark.sql("select count(*) from student_table where student_scores is NULL") \
spark.sql("select count(*) from student_table where student_health is NULL")
```

I get a result that looks like \

```
+-------+|count(1)|\n-------+|    0|+-------+\n|count(1)|\n-------+|    100|+-------+\n|count(1)|\n-------+|  24145|
```

What I want to do is to make the result into a dataframe for each column by using pandas or pyspark function.
The result should have each null value result for each column. 
For example,

[image]

Thanks in advance if someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You could use union between the 3 queries but actually you can get all null counts for each column using one query:

```
spark.sql("""
    SELECT  SUM(INT(student_id IS NULL))     AS student_id_nb_null,
            SUM(INT(student_scores IS NULL)) AS student_scores_nb_null,
            SUM(INT(student_health IS NULL)) AS student_health_nb_null,
    FROM    student_table 
""").show()

#+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
#|student_id_nb_null|student_scores_nb_null|student_health_nb_null|
#+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
#|                 0|                   100|                 24145|
#+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Or by using DataFrame API with:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F    

df.agg(
    F.sum(F.col("student_id").isNull().cast("int")).alias("student_id_nb_null"),
    F.sum(F.col("student_scores").isNull().cast("int")).alias("student_scores_nb_null"),
    F.sum(F.col("student_health").isNull().cast("int")).alias("student_health_nb_null")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `union all` and add all your queries in one `spark.sql`.

**`Example:`**

```
spark.sql("""select "student_id" `column_name`,count(*) `null_result` from tmp where student_id is null \
union all \
select "student_scores" `column_name`,count(*) `null_result` from tmp where student_scores is null \
union all \
select "student_health" `column_name`,count(*) `null_result` from tmp where student_health is null""").\
show()
```